# kivyMD statistical analysis

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

let us suppose we have following table
[image]

to display this table in  kivyMD, i have implemented following code :

```
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
import pandas as pd
data =pd.read_csv("Data.csv")
class  Read_CsvApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen =MDScreen()
        self.data_tables =MDDataTable(pos_hint={
        'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5
        },check=True,use_pagination=True,
            column_data=[
                ("No.", dp(30)),
                ("Product_Name", dp(30)),
                ("Product_Price", dp(30)),
                ("Product_Demand", dp(30)),

            ],
        row_data = [tuple(row)  for index,row  in data.iterrows()
           ]
        )
        screen.add_widget(self.data_tables)
        return  screen

if __name__ =="__main__":
    Read_CsvApp().run()
```

if we run this code, we get:
[image]

now let us suppose i want to create a button which will multiply price  on demand  and  create a new column called as Revenue :  could you  please give me a way how to do it? if it is possible at all, thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you will have to create a new `MDDataTable` that includes the new column, remove the old `MDDataTable` from the `Screen`, then add the new one.

Comment: and what about multiplication?  should i  do it in pandas DataFrame or?